# json_object_t : ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed

Tags: json, oracle, oracle19c, oracle-rest-data-services

Im getting an exception when I run the below code in oracle database, how to handle it, pl help

Error report -
ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed
ORA-06512: at line 7
30625. 00000 -  "method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed"
*Cause:    A member method of a type is being invoked with a NULL SELF
argument.
*Action:   Change the method invocation to pass in a valid self argument.

```
declare
m_top_obj               json_object_t;
m_paymentDetails_obj    json_object_t;
begin
m_top_obj := json_object_t.parse('{"reference": "hello"}');
m_paymentDetails_obj := m_top_obj.get_object('paymentDetails');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(m_paymentDetails_obj.get_string('reference'));
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no `paymentDetails` attribute in the JSON, so `m_paymentDetails_obj` is null.

Check this before trying to access attributes in it:

```
declare
  m_top_obj               json_object_t;
  m_paymentDetails_obj    json_object_t;
begin
  m_top_obj := json_object_t.parse('{"reference": "hello"}');
  m_paymentDetails_obj := m_top_obj.get_object('paymentDetails');
  if m_paymentDetails_obj is not null then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(m_paymentDetails_obj.get_string('reference'));
  else 
    dbms_output.put_line ( 'no paymentDetails' );
  end if;
end;
/
no paymentDetails
```

Comment: Ahh. Why not null check didn't strike in my mind. I was exploring all the memeber methods to handle null object. Thank you so much for your help Chris!!!